# could not convert {...} from <brace-enclosed initializer list> to struct

Tags: c++, gcc, struct, initialization

I'd previously used TDM-GCC-5.10 and now switched back to 4.9 MINGW-GCC and getting a weird error with trying to use list-initialization:

```
class Vector2
{
public:
    Vector2(float x, float y)
    {
        this->x = x;
        this->y = y;
    }
    float x = 0.f;
    float y = 0.f;
};

struct Test
{
    int x = 0;
    Vector2 v;
};

int main()
{    
    Test tst = {0,Vector2(0.0f,0.0f)}; //Error
    return 0;
}
```

Error:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:21:41: error: could not convert '{0, Vector2(0.0f, 0.0f)}' from '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'Test'
         Test tst = {0,Vector2(0.0f,0.0f)}; //Error
                                         ^
```

I used C++14 with both compilers. What is wrong?

Comment: There is no `main` in the question. See [ask] and provide a [mcve].

Comment: @Olaf Edited, just copy and try to run it.

Comment: Rolled back to previous version. You are not supposed to edit a question once you have an answer if that edit removes the context for that answer. You might append an explanation, though if that is clearly marked as such.

Comment: But the Answer is pointless because it has nothing to do with the Question.

Comment: @Olaf: I disagree. By that logic any question with a typo should keep it if someone answered that there is a typo.

Comment: @Dani: That's how it works, though. OP is free to DV the answer and add  a clarification to the question. There was enough time to provide a [mcve], which implies the code **does compile** and is complete, i.e. exactly what OP used. An alternative would be to kindly ask the answerer to remove her answer first.

Comment: I think the older compiler doesn't implement/enable all cpp14 features. Did you specify in the command line to use cpp14?

Comment: @Dani: `cpp` is commonly know as the "C PreProcessor". You mean C++14.

Comment: @Dani Yes i used -std=c++14

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
struct Test
{
    int x = 0; // <==
    Vector2 v;
};
```

Until recently, default member initializer prevent the class from being an aggregate, so you cannot use aggregate initialization on them. Gcc 4.9 still implements the old rules here, whereas gcc 5 uses the new ones.

Comment: Unbelievable, this even influences forward compatibility. They should never have done this change! Also a problem that this works perfectly with VC2017!

Comment: @DrumM I don't understand the comment - what influences compatibility? What change should never have been done?

Comment: Like you said, when the class is not an aggregate anymore, the default constructor is not generated. Maybe it's wrong to say "it's not forward compatible" because we are using a new feature. But in my opinion, the specification is a mess, why would you still need to implement a default constructor if you specify default initialization on a member... Doesn't make sense.

Comment: @DrumM Huh? `Test` here has a default constructor. What do you still need to implement?

Comment: @DrumM "Like you said, when the class is not an aggregate anymore, the default constructor is not generated" - I never said that.

Comment: yes I was wrong. I didn't mean the 'default' constructor, I meant the constructor `Test(int, Vector2)`

Comment: @DrumM That constructor has never existed.

Comment: Yes, correct. So the way you can initialize using braces: aggregate initialization. I don't see why a class with a default member init would prevent you from doing that...

Comment: @DrumM It DOESNT prevent you from doing it. It USED TO - it does not anymore.

Answer (score 3):

You missed `;` after your class definition and after `int x = 0`. Then you got many errors and apparently only considered the last one. But your compiler was confused because `Vector2` was not defined (due to missing `;`).

This compiles:

```
int main()
{
    class Vector2
    {
    public:
        Vector2(float x, float y)
        {
            this->x = x;
            this->y = y;
        }
        float x = 0.f;
        float y = 0.f;
    };

    struct Test
    {
        int x;
        Vector2 v;
    };

    Test tst = {0,Vector2(4,5)};
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry just added them, which compiler Version and standard do you use? And this is not caused by the missing ; (i forgot only in this example) everything worked fine with the TDM-GCC Compiler.

Comment: g++ 4.8.4 with option `-std=c++11`. Note that I also removed (accidentally) `= 0` to Test's `x` declaration. Adding it apparently leads to a compiler error.

Comment: Looks like i have a problem with the compiler if i remove any dialect option it compiles but with c++11/c++14 it brings me this error.